# Unknown props warning when passing props to children

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a reusable dropdown menu wrapper component using this pattern:

```
class DropdownMenu extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        {React.cloneElement(
          this.props.children, 
          {  
            menuOpen: this.props.menuOpen,
            toggleMenu: this.props.toggleMenu
          }
        )}
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const HeaderUserDropdown = ({menuOpen, toggleMenu }) => (
  <DropdownMenu>
    <div className={menuOpen ? 'visible' : ''}>
      <button onClick={toggleMenu} />
    </div>
  </DropdownMenu>
)
```

But I get an error along the lines of `Warning: Unknown props menuOpen, toggleMenu on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element.` I know that I can use `data-` to get this working correctly, but that seems sort of hacky. What's the correct way to pass these props down to the children?

Comment: i think you must re-check your code twice. that `menuOpen: this.props,menuOpen,` you should have to change that `,` to `.`

Comment: Thanks, fixed. This was just pseudocode anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React distinguishes between HTML elements which are written in lower case (e.g. `<div>`) and React components which start with a capital letter.

In your code, you're trying to clone an HTML div element and add the properties `menuOpen` and `toggleMenu`, but these attributes are not supported by `<div>`, hence the warning. You need to set custom attributes on an HTML element, you'll need to use the `data-` prefix convention.

Comment: So there's no way to use this pattern without the `data-` prefix?

Comment: Correct. React prints the warning because it will not set unsupported attributes on the underlying HTML elements.